# mongodb connection to atlas cluster

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to my atlas cluster using `connect()` method  and getting error as `"No Primary Detected"`.

Here are the steps i performed:

1. Run the mongo shell from command prompt.
2. Execute load(); by passing the script file name.

File contains below script:

```
var url = "mongodb://leeban-m001-shard-00-00-sqjjv.mongodb.net:27017,leeban-m001-shard-00-01-sqjjv.mongodb.net:27017,leeban-m001-shard-00-02-sqjjv.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Leeban-M001-shard-0";
var userName="mongo-m001";
var password="******";

var database = connect(url, userName, password);
```

When I execute the command through shell (without using connect method.) I am able to connect to Atlas cluster.

Is `connect()` method will work to connect to mongodb clusters?

Comment: This is common for users who have not whitelisted their IP address.  Please review the Security/IP Whitelists for your inbound client IP.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the `authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1` option to your connection string?

The following script should work:

```
var url = "mongodb://leeban-m001-shard-00-00-sqjjv.mongodb.net:27017,leeban-m001-shard-00-01-sqjjv.mongodb.net:27017,leeban-m001-shard-00-02-sqjjv.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Leeban-M001-shard-0&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1";
var userName="mongo-m001";
var password="******";

var database = connect(url, userName, password);
```

I hope this helps!